# Xcode 8.2.1 Accessibility Inspector not working with iOS 9 devices

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility

I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.3 that I've been using for development for quite a while not and have no issues deploying my code on it and debugging with Xcode 8.2.1.  The Accessibility Inspector has a "(not setup)" next to this iPhone in the drop down list to select the item to inspect.  If I pick the device it puts up an alert that says:

> Device Not Setup
>
> This device must be setup for development using Xcode.

I am very confused by this message because I am able to deploy and debug on it.  I see nothing in Xcode about needing any additional setup for the device.

I have another team member whose iOS 9.x.x devices are experiencing the same issue.  I am beginning to wonder if it has something to do with the iOS version being 9.x.  Unfortunately we can't upgrade these devices to iOS 10 at this time.  Also I have no issues with another device I have for development that is running iOS 10.

Is there a compatibility issue between the Accessibility Inspector in Xcode 8.2.1 and iOS 9.x devices?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have this same issue with Xcode 12.1 and an iOS 9.3.5 device.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue by xcode version 8.3.2 (actually all of versions by 8.x.x have problem) and ios 9  and ios 10

I am not sure what was your need and actually I see you have asked your question a long time ago; But I am writing another way to access frame of view and its constraints if you or another developers have this peoblem;

I have run app on device and goes to a view.
At the top of debug area there is a tool bar contains the breakpoint, continue, stop over and ...
[image]
From tools select Debug View Hierarchy

After a while you can see the iphone screen and by left click on a view and choosing Print Description of ... you can see the frame and constraints of UIView
[image]